# How to properly manage active widgets, not loosing focus of them or remember the focus in variable

Tags: python, pyside2

I've got 4 QListView widgets with models(it's not suitable to use QListView or QTableView). And I need to delete a selected item from model and view. And I need one button connected to the function of deletion. So you press the button and one item last selected is gone. But then you select an item in one listview it stays selected, so if I press the button, selected items in 4 QListViews are gone. To deselect items automatically is not an option, because I've got one function which won't work. 
If I try to use .hasFocus(): after I press button, the button gets the focus so nothing happens. I can add another button to deselect at will or use shorcuts, but for me it's kind of clumsy.

So I need a way to either the widget not to loose focus, either to understand how to make my program remember which one of 4 widgets had focus the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep track of the widgets that acquire the focus using the focusChanged signal from QApplication and verify if it is one of the QListView.

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Delete")
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.listviews = []
        # create QListView
        for i in range(4):
            lv = QtWidgets.QListView()
            model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
            lv.setModel(model)
            lay.addWidget(lv)
            self.listviews.append(lv)
            for j in range(10):
                it = QtGui.QStandardItem("{}-{}".format(i, j))
                model.appendRow(it)

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlay.addWidget(button)
        vlay.addLayout(lay)

        self._last_listview = None

        QtWidgets.qApp.focusChanged.connect(self.on_focusChanged)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        if self._last_listview is not None:
            for index in reversed(sorted(self._last_listview.selectedIndexes())):
                self._last_listview.model().removeRow(index.row())

    @QtCore.Slot("QWidget*", "QWidget*")
    def on_focusChanged(self, old, now):
        if now in self.listviews:
            self._last_listview = now


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```